# How to display the iAd from apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, iad

i have add the library of `iAd`, in addition of that i dragged the view (banner) to the footer of the application, and i have registered to iTunes connect `iad` and all is clear. But when i test my application of my device I'm only getting the example (You're connected to `iAd`), I'm not getting lives ADS, how i can display them?

I tried to look for a solution but all the tutorial they show you only how to include it, and as I said I'm not getting the advertisements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You advertisements will start automatically after the application is approved. However in the simulator and real device test,the ads that you are seeing are only for test and debug.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH6-SW1 "iAd App Network automatically displays the correct ad depending on the how your app binary was downloaded onto your test device, as shown in Table 4-1."

I haven't used iAd's before but they should start displaying once your add goes live. And I don't think anything but the placeholder ad will display on your device.